# Are these green areas on my cured ham a health problem?

Tags: food-safety, ham, drying, curing

In below images I highlighted a green coloration on my cured boar ham. It cured for 5 days in an open plastic box in my cellar. I put a lot of salt around it and a weight on top (it was maybe 75% submerged and fully coated with salt and powdered celery).

I then hung them in my cellar, but when I was cleaning them I saw what I encircled in the images below. These seem to be near the holes we used to hang the animal from. When I smell the holes there is a very faint smell of maybe sweat or something. It is hard to tell if it is actually a bad smell from the boar or not.

This is my first time curing/drying meat so I am not very confident obviously, can anyone see if I have a problem? (P.S. I know the lighting is not ideal in the pictures, sorry)
[image]

Comment: It's not going to be possible for us to determine safety.  However, I will say that 5 days in salt does not sound like long enough for something that size.  For example, when I make bacon, pancetta, or guanciale, I am curing for at least a week...and that is for pork belly or jowl...significantly thinner.   Recipes for home-cured prosciutto that I have encountered call for 3 to 4 weeks in salt.